# Filtering , classifying and creating a new variable based on a reference datetime

Tags: r, date, filtering, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I am currently working with a dataset containing the records of some water-supply tanks  that shows the **DATE** of  technical inspections of 5 different tanks (**IDENT**) and also the **TYPE** of inspection recorded which can only have two values "READ" when the tank is working properly and "ERROR" when otherwise performing poorly.

| IDENT | DATE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X3 | 30/04/2021 | ERROR |
| X1 | 1/05/2021 | READ |
| X1 | 2/05/2021 | ERROR |
| X4 | 3/05/2021 | READ |
| X9 | 4/05/2021 | ERROR |
| X6 | 5/05/2021 | READ |
| X1 | 6/05/2021 | READ |
| X3 | 7/05/2021 | ERROR |
| X3 | 8/05/2021 | READ |

---

I have to create a dataframe that can filter and select every TYPE="ERROR" **DATE** for each water tank (is there is no error recorded on the dateset for a specify tank is not necessary to show it) and show the latest TYPE="READ" **DATE** prior to the each tank's ERROR and also the latest **DATE** After each tank's error date, to illustrate I am to achieve this table:

```
| IDENT | READ_PRIOR |    ERROR   | POST_READ |
|:-----:|:----------:|:----------:|:---------:|
|   X3  |     NA     | 30/04/2021 | 8/05/2021 |
|   X3  |     NA     |  7/05/2021 | 8/05/2021 |
|   X1  |  1/05/2021 |  2/05/2021 | 6/05/2021 |
|   X9  |     NA     |  4/05/2021 |     NA    |
```

**What Have I tried?**

I have started working on this problem by arranging the data set in chronological order by DATE and also grouping by IDENT using the tidyverse package, also I can select the latest DATE for a group using the top_n function but my issue is that I cant seem to find a way to successfully filter or select the latest dates for a tank before and after the reference TYPE="ERROR" so that's where I am bumping my head. Thank you so much for helping me put guys I truly appreciate it.

Code:

```
df<- tibble::tribble(
~IDENT  ~DATE   ~TYPE,
        
"X3",   "30/04/2021",   "ERROR",
        
"X1",   "1/05/2021",    "READ",
        
"X1",   "2/05/2021",    "ERROR",
        
"X4",   "3/05/2021",    "READ",
        
"X9",   "4/05/2021",    "ERROR",
        
"X6",   "5/05/2021",    "READ",
        
"X1",   "6/05/2021",    "READ",
        
"X3",   "7/05/2021",    "ERROR",
        
"X3",   "8/05/2021",    "READ")
```

Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the 'DATE' column to `Date` class (`dmy` - from lubridate), `arrange` the rows by 'IDENT' and 'DATE', grouped by 'IDENT', recode the 'READ' values to 'READ_PRIOR' and 'POST_READ' with `case_when` based on the presence of 'ERROR', remove the 'IDENT' groups that have no 'ERROR' value in 'TYPE', reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` and `fill` the values in 'POST_READ' with non-NA adjacent values for each 'IDENT'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE)) %>%
  arrange(IDENT, DATE) %>% 
  group_by(IDENT) %>% 
  mutate(TYPE = case_when(TYPE == 'READ' & lead(TYPE) == 'ERROR' 
     ~ 'READ_PRIOR', TYPE == 'READ' ~ 'POST_READ', TRUE ~ TYPE)) %>%       
  filter('ERROR' %in% TYPE) %>%     
  mutate(rn = rowid(IDENT, TYPE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TYPE, values_from = DATE) %>% 
  fill(POST_READ) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  IDENT READ_PRIOR ERROR      POST_READ 
#  <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
#1 X1    2021-05-01 2021-05-02 2021-05-06
#2 X3    NA         2021-04-30 2021-05-08
#3 X3    NA         2021-05-07 2021-05-08
#4 X9    NA         2021-05-04 NA
```

Comment: Awesome! 10/10  I love the way you code is so clean.. thanks for the explanation at the beginning... I have a question (Im learning R) you are using the library data.table what functions exactly depend on this library for the code you use? Thanks so much again thanks a lot

Comment: @R_Student it is just the `rowid`.  If you don't want a depeendency, then use `group_by(IDENT, TYPE) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%`